# Apostrophe changes after sanitizing word

Tags: html, go, text, utf-8, sanitization

```
package main

import (
"log"
"github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday"
)

func main() {
c := "hello doesn't work "

    p := bluemonday.UGCPolicy()
    
    log.Println(p.Sanitize(c))

}
```

the expected output should be
`hello doesn't work` 
instead i receive
`hello doesn&#39;t work`

I try by using allowlist with regexp but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a change in the context of HTML, as you can see below:

```html
<div>hello doesn't work </div>
<div>hello doesn&#39;t work </div>
```